# How do i remove new line character from excel

Tags: excel, newline, cell

I had an excel file which contain new line character data. I need to delete the value preceding new line character. e.g.[image: See Excel example below]
Here what I need to just keep the first value and delete the remaining after new line character. I tried through Find and Replace option but here the preceding text are getting attached with the first text. Can you help me here please.

Comment: How are you looking for the new line, Is it chr(10) or chr(13) etc?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your question. If by looking you mean how am I finding my new line in excel then it is through ctrl+J option in Find and replace option.

Answer (score 0):

Now you've commented back I mistook your initial question.
You should just be able to put `=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1))` in B1 if that's the result you're after?

---

Given your comment I've got the following VBA which would do it, if you have other ranges then feel free to adjust that part:

```
Sub PreLineFeed()
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, InStr(cell.Value, vbLf))
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is now working. Anyways I am looking for a generic solution, my data has lots of column it is not possible to put check on every column also the number of words in a particular cell is not fixed

Comment: OK, I've added an alternative VBA solution in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheet may contain cells with newline characters (ALT+ENTER).Run the following macro to remove newline characters (Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic Editor):

```
' Removing tabs and carriage returns from worksheet cells
Sub CleanUp()
Dim TheCell As Range
On Error Resume Next

For Each TheCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 With TheCell
 If .HasFormula = False Then
   .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Value)
 End If
End With
Next TheCell
End Sub
```

Note - steps to enable and create macro in excel is mentioned in below link

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html